# What is the type of nil?

Tags: go

I want to check for `nil` in a type switch.  What type do I use for `nil` in a switch case?

```
 switch v := v.(type) {
 case int:
      fmt.Println("it's an integer", v)
 case ????:  <--- what type do I put here?
      fmt.Println("it's nil!")
 }
```

Comment: https://thenotexpert.com/golang-typed-nils/

Comment: `nil` is not a type. It's a value. Different types can all have `nil` as value, so it doesn't make any sense to check for the value if you are looking for the type.

Comment: check for nil before the type switch. `v == nil`.  As mentioned, `nil` is not a type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nil` to check for a nil interface value in a type switch:

```
switch v := v.(type) {
case int:
    fmt.Println("it's an integer", v)
case nil:
    fmt.Println("it's nil!")
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0b-QpZkbrWz).

A nil interface value does not have a dynamic type.  In the context of a type switch case, `nil` represents "no dynamic type".

Comment: Is a type switch a regular switch on the type slot in the interface value?   Assuming that the type slot is a pointer,  a nil interface value has a nil type slot.

Answer (score 8):

> I want to check for `nil` in a type switch.  What is the type of `nil`?

There is not a single place in the Go Language Specification that specifies `nil`, but there are multiple places that make it clear that `nil` has no type [**bold** emphasis mine]:

- In the [section on *Variables*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables):

  > unless the value is the predeclared identifier `nil`, which **has no type**
- In the [sub-section on *Expression switches*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expression_switches):

  > The predeclared **untyped** value `nil` […]

Even if the Go Language Specification did not explicitly say that `nil` has no type, it should *at least* be obvious that `nil` *cannot possibly have a single type*. At least not a type that is expressible *within Go*.

`nil` is a *valid value* for

- pointers,
- functions,
- interfaces,
- slices,
- channels, and
- maps.

This means that the type of `nil` *must* be *all* of those types *at the same time*. There are a couple of ways in which this could be achieved: The type of `nil` could be

- a *union type* of all of those types,
- an *intersection type* of all of those types (but that wouldn't be type-safe), or
- a *subtype* of all of those types, or
- a *polymorphic type*.

However, Go doesn't have union types, it doesn't have intersection types, it doesn't have subtyping, and it doesn't have polymorphic types, so *even if* `nil` had a type, this type would not be expressible in Go.

Alternatively, the designers of Go could declare that `nil` doesn't have one type, it has *multiple types*, but that wouldn't help you either: you would have to have cases for all the possible types `nil` can have, but those cases wouldn't apply *only* to `nil`. You would need to have a case for pointers, but that case would apply to *any* pointer not just to a `nil` pointer, and so on.

It *is* possible to check for a *`nil` interface type*, however. See the [sub-section on *Type switches*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches):

> Instead of a type, a case may use the predeclared identifier `nil`; that case is selected when the expression in the *TypeSwitchGuard* is a `nil` interface value. There may be at most one `nil` case.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether `v` is nil outside of your type switch.

```
if v == nil {
   // Do stuff probably return or error out?
}
switch v := v.(type) {
   // ...
}
```